# Do I connect multiple I2C units to the microcontroler in series or parallel?

Tags: sensors, i2c, gps, accelerometer, gyroscope

I have a project (still planning) with three I2C sensors: GPS, 3-axis gyro+accelerometer, and OLED. Do I connect SDA/SCL in series, or do I connect them in parallel?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Wikipedia page on the protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) as an introduction to your learning curve on I<sup>2</sup>C. I may cite:

> At the physical layer, both SCL and SDA lines are [a ...] bus design, [...]

This means that all devices connect in parallel (image from the same page, public domain):

[image]

> Rp are pull-up resistors, Rs are **optional** series resistors. (Emphasis by me)

Answer (score 1):

Connect the three I2C devices in parallel.